# Add a Trailing Slash to Single Url

Tags: webserver, htaccess

Hi I Want to Add Trailing Slash to (/) only a Single URL

The URL I want to add trailing slash is `http://niresh12495.com/index.php`
so it would look like `http://niresh12495.com/index.php/` any htaccess ideas?

I have tried to add trailing slash to all urls but that caused an issue, example:

`niresh12495.com/topic/sometopic/page2/` was redirected back to `niresh12495.com/topic/sometopic/` so there is no way to see the next page it will always redirect to main topic

Comment: You can just use `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(index\.php)$ /$1/` as your first rule.

Answer (score 1):

If the last character on a multi-level filepath is a forward slash, that indicates that the previous name was a directory, not a file. If you really want index.php to represent a directory and not a file, then you would have to create a directory with that name on your server. Then, the htaccess could be modified to omit *.php as a file type, and you could mis-use some other file extension as a default web page type.

Basically, not a good idea. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do after you are able to add a trailing slash to a filename, someone could offer you a better alternative.

Comment: The Reason For Which I'm Asking is i have set up /index.php/ to redirect to root / but it was not possible with /index.php & if i try to rewrite index.php that turns out to be a nightmare because it messes with login & everything around the forum Thanks for this information :)